# Adding Jquery to an new Window "window.open"

Tags: javascript, jquery

what about adding jquery to a page.
Like this:

1. Clicking on a bookmark (which loads the same url into a new window)
2. Adding Jquery.js
3. Run some jquery..

Comment: And what is that you would like to ask about?

Comment: about how.. 
don't get it running. 
i want to include jquery.js, but how.

Answer (score 0):

Take alook at:
[jQuerify Bookmarklet](http://www.learningjquery.com/2006/12/jquerify-bookmarklet)

> It's not only possible to include the
>   jQuery source right from the Firebug
>   console, but you can also add a
>   bookmarklet to your Bookmarks toolbar
>   for one-click jQuery action!

The bookmarklet code:

```
var s=document.createElement('script');
s.setAttribute('src','http://jquery.com/src/jquery-latest.js');
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(s);
```

Comment: that s perfect.. just how to execute this after new page loaded ..?

Comment: I don't get your question. Did you read the article? 
You can use this code to access jQuery on a foreign page. You might also create a popup and register an onload event with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your question is, but I'm going to try to answer it:

To use jQuery you must include the jQuery.js document in a script tag (I'd recommend the head-section).

You can do this by either downloading the jquery document from [jQuerys page](http://jquery.com/) (remember to choose the minified version), put it in a folder and insert the correct path to the jquery document where I typed "jquery.js", and do like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
```

**Note that script must be closed, don't selfclose**

However, you can also use a CDN hosted copy of jQuery. You can choose which CDN you want [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery). This is an example using jquery's own hosted document:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: ok i try to find a better explenation,
your on a page which don't include jquery,
i try to open it in a new window, and include it afterwards.

Comment: Oh! The question makes more sense now!

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to the new window that you will open, before the $(document).ready()

```
var fileref=document.createElement('script');
fileref.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');
fileref.setAttribute('src', 'Jquery.js');
if (typeof fileref!=undefined)
  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref);
```

I need to ask if the site is yours, or you're only testing with the site, if the site isn't yours, you can use firebux and jQuerify, if the site is yours, just add that code between  tags.

Create a link and add this to the href: 
"javascript:var%20s=document.createElement('script');s.setAttribute('src',%20'http://jquery.com/src/jquery-latest.js');document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(s);alert('jQuery Applied');void(s);"

and the drag it to your bookmarks